# What kind of functional groups can give positive silver mirror test?

Tags: organic-chemistry

kindly help me with a mechanism of Tollen's reagent that could explain how it acts as a reagent with organic compounds I wish to understand how we can analyze through **structure** whether a given compound will give a positive silver mirror test or not.

i found a [mechanism](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/13918/mechanism-for-reaction-of-tollens-reagent-with-aldehydes) that explains it's reaction with aldehydes but again it also gives a positive test for terminal triple bond. ([link to that question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/23670/does-acetylene-give-a-positive-tollens-test-if-not-why-is-this-so))
I am unsure whether it could give the test with any other functional group also

link to an article that could give more insight on this would be of great help

p.s. I m really new to asking questions so please do help me in asking better questions and framing them better